# condition with PL/SQL to change row color in APEX

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have created a template on apex on which I change the row color based on TITLE column value. so in the  column template 1 I set the style and hose based on PL/SQL condition and put the condition as:

```
:TITLE = '%Software Engineer%'
```

where title is the column name and software engineer is the value to meet the condition and apply the style. the problem is that nothing happen to the report when I open it and rows with software engineer column values remain the same and not changed. any help?

**UPDATE**
the generated code for the table is like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" summary=""  id="report_R4834108199210951"><tr><td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" summary="" class="report-standard">
<tr ><th id="EMPLOYEE_ID" class="header" style="background-color: blue;"><div class="rpt-sort"><a  href="javascript:$a_report('4834108199210951',false,false,false,'fsp_sort_1_desc')"  title="Sort by this column">Employee Id</a><img align="absmiddle" src="/i/arrow_up_gray_dark.gif" width="13" height="12" alt="Sort by this column" /></div></th><th id="FIRSTNAME" class="header" style="background-color: blue;"><div class="rpt-sort"><a  href="javascript:$a_report('4834108199210951',false,false,false,'fsp_sort_2')"  title="Sort by this column">Firstname</a></div></th><th id="LASTNAME" class="header" style="background-color: blue;"><div class="rpt-sort"><a  href="javascript:$a_report('4834108199210951',false,false,false,'fsp_sort_3')"  title="Sort by this column">Lastname</a></div></th><th id="TITLE" class="header" style="background-color: blue;"><div class="rpt-sort"><a  href="javascript:$a_report('4834108199210951',false,false,false,'fsp_sort_4')"  title="Sort by this column">Title</a></div></th></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td align="right"  headers="EMPLOYEE_ID" class="data">1</td><td headers="FIRSTNAME" class="data">Moustapha</td><td headers="LASTNAME" class="data">Cherry</td><td headers="TITLE" class="data">Consultant</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td align="right"  headers="EMPLOYEE_ID" class="data">2</td><td headers="FIRSTNAME" class="data">Amal</td><td headers="LASTNAME" class="data">Khalil</td><td headers="TITLE" class="data">Practice Manager</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td align="right"  headers="EMPLOYEE_ID" class="data">3</td><td headers="FIRSTNAME" class="data">Yehia</td><td headers="LASTNAME" class="data">Elhady</td><td headers="TITLE" class="data">Senior Software Engineer</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td align="right"  headers="EMPLOYEE_ID" class="data">4</td><td headers="FIRSTNAME" class="data">Ehab </td><td headers="LASTNAME" class="data">Sultan</td><td headers="TITLE" class="data">Software Engineer</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td align="right"  headers="EMPLOYEE_ID" class="data">5</td><td headers="FIRSTNAME" class="data">Ayat</td><td headers="LASTNAME" class="data">Faissal</td><td headers="TITLE" class="data">Team Leader</td></tr>
<tr class="highlight-row"><td align="right"  headers="EMPLOYEE_ID" class="data">6</td><td headers="FIRSTNAME" class="data">Muhammad</td><td headers="LASTNAME" class="data">Alramahy</td><td headers="TITLE" class="data">Software Engineer</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
:TITLE like '%Software Engineer%'
```

Or:

```
:TITLE = 'Software Engineer'
```